# How to set a Vacation Responder in Google Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Is it possible to set a vacation responder in Google Inbox? I could not find a respective option in the settings menu.

Comment: Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes** just not directly.

Since Inbox is actually an extension to the Gmail service many of the finer settings can only be set from the Gmail settings menu. Vacation responder is one of these settings.

To get to Gmail from Inbox you can simply type in Gmail.com as the URL, if you have *Redirect Gmail to inbox.google.com* checked then you need to choose Gmail from the Inbox menu first.

[image]

1. From your Gmail go to **settings**
   [image]
2. On the **General** Tab scroll to the bottom.
   [image]
3. Select the radio button **Vacation responder on**
4. Fill in your responder details, *start date*, *end date* (optional), *subject line*, and *message*.
5. Select **Save Changes** at the bottom.

These changes *WILL* carry over to Inbox.

Comment: Thank you! You need to make sure then that the [redirect setting](http://i.imgur.com/wyVBwy6.png) in Inbox is not checked.

Comment: You can leave that checked because you only need to return to Gmail to get to the correct settings.  You can get there from the menu in Inbox when you need to change the setting.